# Dropdown menu disappears before clicking

Tags: html, css

I have created header with dropdown menu. I want it to be hoverable but dropdown menu dissappears before i can click or hover over it.

I am using transition but before that, it was the same. what am i missing?
I donot know javascript. So i only want to use css.

```css
.logo > a {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    letter-spacing: .1em;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}


.navbar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    width: 60%;
    font-size: .75em;
    font-weight: 700;
}


.nav-items {
    width: 100%;
}


.nav-items > ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
    justify-content: space-between;
}


.nav-items ul li > a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}


.nav-items ul div div > a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
}


input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}
.drop1,
.drop2 {
    position: relative;
}

.drop-menu {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3em;
    background-color: #000;
    font-size: .8em;
    text-align: start;
    visibility: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    max-height: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}


.drop-menu > a {
    padding: .9em 6em .9em .9em;
    white-space: nowrap;
}


.nav-items label {
    cursor: pointer;
}



.nav-items input:hover + .drop-menu {
    visibility: visible;
    max-height: 2000px;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1;
}


.drop-menu > a:hover {
    background-color:rgb(103, 111, 117);
}



.nav-items input:checked ~ .drop-menu {

}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="menu">
            <div class="logo"><a href="#" >TASTIES</a></div>
            <div class="navbar">
                <input type="checkbox" class="toggler" id="checkbox">
                <div class="hamburger"><div></div></div>
                <div class="nav-items">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <div class="drop1">
                            <label for="drop1">Recipes</label>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="drop1">
                            <div class="drop-menu">
                                <a href="">Meat Recipes</a>
                                <a href="">Veggie Recipes</a>
                                <a href="">Deserts</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="drop2">
                            <label for="drop2">Cooking Tips</label>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="drop2">
                            <div class="drop-menu">
                                <a href="#">Preparing Tips</a>
                                <a href="#">Cooking Tips</a>
                                <a href="#">Presentation Tips</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <li><a href="#">Drinks</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
```

I want it to be hoverable with transition effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap dropdowns `div` with `li` tag. Inside `ul` you should only use `li` elements.
Add common class on dropdowns, for example: `<div class="drop1 dropdown">` and use this selector to add hover effect: `.nav-items .dropdown:hover > .drop-menu`

Answer (score 0):

To complete @StasAmasev answer, you can do something like this :

```
<li><a href="#">Home</a>
    <div class="drop1">
       <label for="drop1">Recipes</label>
         <input type="checkbox" id="drop1">
         <div class="drop-menu">
             <a href="">Meat Recipes</a>
             <a href="">Veggie Recipes</a>
             <a href="">Deserts</a>
         </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

And with the following css :

```
.nav-items li:hover .drop-menu {
   visibility: visible;
   max-height: 2000px;
   opacity: 1;
   z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i think i missed the logic what to hover.

Comment: Yes, don't forget `<ul>` should only contain `<li>`. Also don't use `<input>` here as well as `<label>`, those are for forms ! Prefer `<span>Recipes</span>` in your case.

Comment: I am going to change menu for smaller screens and make the dropdown menus clickable using ":checked" in the css. How can i do it differently without using label or input?

Comment: Using `:hover` and `:focus` will work like a charm on mobile for example. I advice you to take a look at existing website and how they do it!

Answer (score -1):

You could also just wrap `<div class="drop-menu">` with your `<label>` tag, like this:

```
                    <div class="drop1">
                        <label for="drop1">Recipes
                          <input type="checkbox" id="drop1">
                          <div class="drop-menu">
                            <a href="">Meat Recipes</a>
                            <a href="">Veggie Recipes</a>
                            <a href="">Deserts</a>
                          </div>
                        </label>
                    </div>
```

See https://codepen.io/nosnetrom/pen/bJLoQx.

Comment: This is invalid. A `label` can't have block elements like `div`'s as children